# Add different values of tooltips with more than one series

Tags: react-native, charts, highcharts, tooltip

I have a problem with adding different values in tooltips in my chart using React-Native.
We have 3 series of my graph. The first shows the bars and the others are lines.
When I click on the bar I load a tooltip with the value "this.y" which is what I need and it works.
But when I click the in lines I need to load other values into the tooltips.
But I can't load these values. Clicking doesn't open the tooltip.

```
//Bar data
this.state.barArray = [10.1, 22.5, 33.3, 4.5, 1.5, 26.3, 17, 18.20, 9.2, 0.9, 1, 2];

//Line 1 data
this.state.line1Array = [12.1, 21.5, 23.3, 14.5, 13.5, 16.3, 15, 18.12, 19.2, 10.9, 0, 2.5];

//Line 2 data
this.state.line2Array = [13.1, 18.5, 13.3, 24.5, 19.5, 23.3, 10.3, 16.40, 29.2, 5.9, 21.3, 0];

//X axis of chart
this.state.dias = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

//Here I load 2 arrays with the values. I want to display on each line
var toolTip = ['2h 30m','1h 30m','4h 30m','5h 30m','6h 30m','4h 30m','1h 30m','7h 30m','15h 30m','2h 13m','12h 30m','00h 30m'];

var toolTip2 = ['1h 30m','1h 30m','4h 30m','5h 30m','6h 30m','4h 30m','1h 30m','7h 30m','15h 30m','2h 13m','12h 30m','00h 30m'];
```

Graph configuration.

```
var conf={
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: null,
        },
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    colors: 
        ['#DA6AFF', 'rgb(71, 40, 213)', 'rgb(172, 143, 242)'], //Bar and lines colors
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: this.state.dias 
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column', //First serie with bar
        name: 'Bar',
        data: this.state.barArray, 
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            shared: false,
            pointFormatter: function() {
                return '<b>Value: ' + this.y + '</b>';
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: 'line', //Second serie with first line
        name: 'Line 1',
        data: this.state.line1Array,
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            shared: false,
            pointFormatter: function() {
                Highcharts.each(toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p) {
                    return '<b>' + p + '</b>';
                });
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: 'line', //Second serie with second line
        name: 'Line 2',
        data: this.state.line2Array,
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            shared: false,
            pointFormatter: function() {
                Highcharts.each(toolTip2[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p) {
                    return '<b>' + p + '</b>';
                });
            }
        }
    }],

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
    },
};

const options = {
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    },
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: ',',
        thousandsSep: '.'
    }
};
```

I did this through the example of this link http://jsfiddle.net/o2zmLngr/5/, but I could not reproduce it in React-Native.

Can anyone help me to create individual tooltips for my chart line and loading information from other arrays?

Comment: Hi @user1182833, Could you reproduce this problem in some online code editor? For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/1q7r99nyx4

Comment: Please try to keep the additional tooltip information as a custom chart property. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9d4awnzc/